# The answer to the complex number equation

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Prove that all the answers to the equation
$$(z+1)(z+2)\cdots (z+n)=n!$$
lie inside or on the circle with radius $n$ centered at $(-n,0)$ in the complex plane.

Comment: $(z+n)!$ does not equal $zn!$

Comment: For us to help you, we need to know the original question. What is this equation?

Comment: @FShrike I wrote the original question. and (z+n)!=z(z+1)(z+2)...(z+n) so we have (z+1)(z+2)...(z+n)=(z+n)!/z

Comment: I see - the phrasing of the question was poor. You want to find all solutions $z$ to $(z+1)(z+2)\cdots(z+n)=n!$ for a given natural number $n$, and show that they reside in a certain circle.

Comment: A good starting point would be recognising that $(z+n)!=(z+n)(z+n-1)\cdots2\cdot1$, which is *not* $z(z+1)(z+2)\cdots(z+n)$. That is the rising pochhammer symbol $z^\underline{n}$ I believe

Comment: @FShrike I understand now. You are right. thanks

Comment: @FShrike can you give me a hint and help me to solve it?

Comment: Can you find an inequality related to the circle? E.g., is it possible for a complex $z$ with $|z+n|\gt n$ to be a solution? The solutions cannot be found analytically as far as I’m aware, so inequalities will be your friend

Comment: @FShrike Yes I know that we should say the answer of equation should be |z+n|<n cause It shows  all the circles with the information of the question. but how to prove this is the solution of this equation?

Comment: If $|z+n|\gt n$, then... $|z+1|\cdot|z+2|\cdots|z+n|\gt ?$

Comment: @FShrike I understand what you say. If |z+n|>n, then... |z+1|⋅|z+2|⋯|z+n|> n! but the problem is that we should say the reverse. I mean we should prove that If  (z+1)(z+2)...(z+n)=n! then |z+n|<=n

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, note that if $ \alpha \in \mathbb{C}$ is a solution to the given equation, then
$$ \vert (\alpha+1) (\alpha+2)\cdots (\alpha +n) \vert = \vert n! \vert = n!.$$
Now, by contradiction, assume that there is a solution, say $ w $, for the given equation outside the mentioned circle. Hence $$ \vert w-(-n) \vert = \vert w + n \vert > n. $$

Using triangle inequality, for every $ j$, $~j = 1, \ldots, n$, we have:
\begin{equation*}
\vert w + j \vert = \vert w + n - (n-j) \vert \geq \vert w + n \vert - \vert n - j \vert > n - (n-j) = j.
\end{equation*}
Therefore,
$ \vert (w+1)\vert \times \vert (w+2) \vert \times \cdots \times \vert(w +n) \vert > 1 \times 2 \times \cdots \times n = n! $ which implies that
$$ \vert (w+1) (w+2)\cdots (w +n) \vert > n!,$$
a contradiction, and we are done.